# How can I use media query with emotion/styled/macro?

Tags: reactjs, emotion

I cannot find any code that using styled macro with media query and don't understand why It's so rare to find code using `emotion/styled/macro`.

I know it allows css style in object literal

```
const StyledUl = styled("ul")(
    {
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        height: "200px",
        width: "100%",
        overflowY: "scroll",
        position: "absolute",
        margin: 0,
        padding: "5px",
        boxShadow: "-1px 15px 34px -21px rgba(0,32,86,0.21)",
        boxSizing: "border-box",
        borderRadius: "8px",
        zIndex: 9999,
    }
)
```

But how can I use `media` query?
And where can I find documentation about `emotion/styled/macro`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing special is required. Just add a `@media ...` query as a property:

```js
import styled from "@emotion/styled/macro";

const StyledUl = styled("ul")({
  "@media (max-width: 600px)": {
    backgroundColor: "#000",
    color: "#fff"
  },
  backgroundColor: "#fff",
  height: "200px",
  width: "calc(100% - 40px)",
  overflowY: "scroll",
  position: "absolute",
  margin: 0,
  padding: "5px",
  boxShadow: "-1px 15px 34px -21px rgba(0,32,86,0.21)",
  boxSizing: "border-box",
  borderRadius: "8px",
  zIndex: 9999
});

export default StyledUl;
```

Optionally, you can use a template literal to style a `styled.HTMLElement`:

```js
import styled from "@emotion/styled/macro";

const StyledUlTemplate = styled.ul`
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
  }

  background-color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: -1px 15px 34px -21px rgba(0, 32, 86, 0.21);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  z-index: 9999;
`;

export default StyledUlTemplate;
```

Demo (drag the middle bar left/right to resize the `Browser` tab to trigger the style changes):

[image: Edit Emotion Media Property in Object]

Comment: I personally don't want to use template literal because I'm using emacs and don't want to set up syntax highlighter for this... :( But this is what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: Btw is there any advantage I can take by using template?

Comment: The two advantages are that within template literals, CSS properties can automatically be interpolated: `color: ${props => props.color || "#fff" };`; whereas, in objects they either need the `css` helper function (which uses a template literal) or you need to pass a function that returns an object: `styled("ul")(props => ({ color: props.color || "#fff" }))`. And the other advantage is interpolating multiple properties is much easier to do and straight forward in template literals.

Comment: I thought using object is also easy when it comes to using props inside but indeed it looks much handy in template. Thank you so much for replying.

Comment: It's been a while since you've answered this question but would you also happen to know how to use pseudo class like `before` in object?

Comment: Updated demo to include an example of using pseudo selectors (see `Toggle.js`).

Answer (score 0):

So I don't think there is any way to slip in media queries with emotion, but you can just wrap around and like classify an id or className instead to any css variable that you haven't defined wih emotion/styled. Emotion is super cool because it can read application state and javaScript and everything, but if you do need to optimize for cell phone or half screen or whatever media queries then this is how I did it. (In React) Basically the trick here is to utilize emotion/styled with like anything you need to adjust with JavaScript or React/angular/vue. But leave everything out that you need adjusted with Media queries and just like simple assign the id or classname for the media queries.

```
  render() {

    const VolunteersContainer = styled.div`
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    background: rgb(250, 248, 248);
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    height:  ${85 + this.state.number * 30}px;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 10px darkgray;
    font-family: Georgia, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }`;
```

and then like don't specify like width or whatever you need your media queries (cell phone or half size to work with)

and then just define it like this:

```
<VolunteersContainer className='volunteerscontainer'>
      <h4 style={{fontFamily: "Gerogia", marginBottom: 15}}><b>Registered Administrators</b></h4>
  {volunteerList}
  </VolunteersContainer>
```

Lets say if width is my media query example right, then note that I never defined emotion/styled to override my className or Id here with width. I never defined it with emotion/styled, but I did with traditional css by using className or Id instead; (like import css classnames and id to this component or tag)

I needed both JavaScript and media queries. Emotion accomplishes JavaScript, which is like amazing. I get height changing beautifully; I needed to adjust height based on React application state by the number of people listed to make the box bigger and like higher, but I still needed media queries to work with width for cell phone and half size browsers, so I just didn't define width and used className or Id instead because it still like accepts ids and classnames so just don't define anything you need with media queries and just like attach the id or className instead.